# Magento 2 - How to get the currentStoreId() from external App?

Tags: magento-2.0

I asked this question in [Magento Stack Exchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127672/magento-2-how-to-get-the-currentstoreid-from-external-app) but did not get any comment/answer from anyone. So I deleted the question over there and asking the same question in SO.

So, I have an external App which logs an admin user into the admin panel. Barebone structure is as follows:

```
 <?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

class TestApp extends \Magento\Framework\App\Http implements \Magento\Framework\AppInterface {

    protected $_resource = null;
    protected $storeManager = null;

    public function __construct(
    //ActionContext $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource, \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager, \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
    // \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession,
    //    \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
    ) {
        $this->_resource = $resource;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function launch() {
        $currentStoreID = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();
    }

}

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('TestApp');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

I have stripped off the actual login part because this is out of the context of this question.

If I call `$this->storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();`, it returns the default store ID, which is not what I want. This application resides under a sub-store (not sure if that's the correct term to use) and I want the current store ID, not the default one.

Following up, I found this [closed issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4371) where the user was told to use `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver::getCurrentStoreId`. `$this->storeManager` does have `storeResolver` inside but that's a protected property, thus inaccessible.

My question is, how do I get the current store ID and not the default one?